# Reference a cell of other worksheet while incrementing the Row number by 15 every time

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get value of sheet 1 cell "A19" in cell "A1" of sheet 2 and sheet 1 cell "A36" (which is 19+15) in cell "A2" of sheet 2. Do not want to use VBA as the number of rows in the sheets is high. have tried indirect function but havent been able to figure out how to reference cell from other workbook. is there any way this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Sheet2*, cell **A1** enter:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,19+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*17)
```

and copy down.

This will retrieve the data from these rows:

```
19
36
53
70
87
104
121
138
155
172
189
206
```

That is because the increment between  19 and 36 is ***17***.
If you really want the increment to be ***15***, then substitute ***15*** in the top equation before the copy-down.

Comment: not sure why you have used ROWS?    `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,19+(ROW()-1)*17)` is fine

Comment: @StevenMartin  Good question!   I use *ROWS()* in cases like this in case I later want to insert rows above the list of output cells.  For example, to add  a row of labels, etc................ *ROWS($1:1)* always begins with ***1*** no matter where in the worksheet it is placed !

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, you can also use INDIRECT  ,  but INDIRECT is volatile so INDEX is a better choice

=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&1+(ROW()-1)*2)